# didReceiveMemoryWarning Messages to Apps in Background - Memory Management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory, memory-management

Does an app running in the background on the iPhone / iPad receive memory management warnings and, if so, when does it receive and act on these (e.g immediately or only when the app becomes active again).

Also would the viewDidUnload method be called on an app's views if that app is running in the background ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not try on the simulator? Put the app in the background and press the simulate memory warning button.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fully replicate the way the iPad / phone behaves when a memory warning is sent - i.e it doesn't start destroying uiviews in inactive apps, which it will do on a live device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone allow only limited functionality to be used when the app is running in background ..So viewDidLoad will not be called when app is running in background ....

Comment: So is nothing called on an app on the background ? When I relaunch an app after a memory warning, some of the views are sometimes destroyed and the app will restart.

Comment: you can run location based services, push notification and audio services even if the app is running in background. When you relaunch the background application it will launch from the state in which it went to background.

Comment: Is viewDidUnload (not viewDidLoad) called ?

Comment: viewDidUnload is also not called when apps enter in background ....even viewDidDisappear: is also not called ..